# VSCode + Neovim Cursor Position Goes Off-Screen While Scrolling By Line (ctrl-e)

Tags: visual-studio-code, neovim, vertical-scrolling, cursor-position, neovim-plugin

While using the [VSCode Neovim plugin](https://github.com/vscode-neovim/vscode-neovim) I've noticed a difference in how the cursor position is handled while vertically scrolling by line with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>.

In stand-alone Neovim/Vim, as the window scrolls the cursor is advanced if it is about to go off-screen, staying at the top of the window:

[image: the cursor stays within the window while vertical-scrolling in Neovim]

But in VSCode + Neovim the cursor stays put, going off-screen. Once this happens, pressing a movement key like <kbd>j</kbd> will cause the window to jump back to the original cursor location, which can be jarring:

[image: the cursor stays put, going off-screen, while vertical-scrolling in VSCode + Neovim]

Is it possible to have the VSCode + Neovim experience match the stand-alone Neovim experience while scrolling with regard to cursor position?

I would think it should be possible, because the cursor **is** updated when page-scrolling with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>:

[image: the cursor is correctly advanced while page-scrolling in VSCode + Neovim]

- VSCode -> `v1.81.1`
- VSCode Neovim plugin -> `v1.7.0`
- Neovim -> `v0.10.0-dev`
- WSL2